# Angular2 remove click event binding after first click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my application I have a button with a click even on it:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" (click)="doSomething()">
```

From within the `doSomething` method, is there any way to remove the `(click)` event from the button (so the user can't trigger the functionnality anymore?).

I tried to set a disabled prop on the button but it doesn't change Angular2 behavior.

I tryed to use `(click)="doSomething($event)` and then

```
doSomething($event) {
  // My method logic goes here
  ...
  ...
  console.log('Method Logic');

  //Attempt to overwrite click event
  let target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
  this.renderer.listen(target, 'click', (event) => {
      console.log('clic block');
    });
}
```

But It doesn't "replace" the click event. So after that, on click, both original logic and the "click block" console log are triggered!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do if you can't unclick the event?

Answer (score 6):

**Method 1**:

You can set a `boolean` variable, so if the user calls the function, `boolean` value changes and the user will be able to call the function on click again but actually nothing will happen.

```
bool: boolean = true;

doSomething($event) {
  if (this.bool) {
    // My method logic goes here
    ...
    ...
    console.log('Method Logic');
    this.bool = false;
  }
}
```

**Method 2**:

You can add a condition to your html component, if specified variable (in this case `bool`) is true, the function is going to be executed, but only once because the `bool` variable will be set to false and the `click` function will execute nothing (null) from now on.

```
bool: boolean = true;

doSomething($event) {
  // My method logic goes here
  ...
  ...
  console.log('Method Logic');
  this.bool = false;
}
```

`(click)="bool ? doSomething($event) : null"`

Comment: I like guard clauses: `if(!this.bool) return;` ... looks cleaner.

Comment: @SparK Same here, but I just wanted to clarify the code as much as it possible.

Comment: It was so simple I didn't think about it! Thanks. I like guard too.

Answer (score 5):

The downside of just adding a guard variable for the execution is that the actual event listener is still in place and will trigger Angular's change detection when clicked, even though it doesn't do anything.

To actually remove the event listener, you have to add it via the component's `Renderer`. This will return a function that removes the event listener when called:

```js
import {Component, AfterViewInit, Renderer, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `<button #button>...</button>`
})
export class SampleComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('button') button: ElementRef;
  private cancelClick: Function;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cancelClick = this.renderer.listen(this.button.nativeElement, 'click',
      ($event: any) => this.handleClick($event));
  }

  handleClick($event: any) {
    this.cancelClick();
    // ...
  }
}
```

If your goal is to just remove the event listener when the event is fired for the first time, this can be implemented as a plugin to Angular's event system. I added it as a part of my [ng2-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-events#once--only-fire-event-listener-once) utility library [[source]](https://github.com/kryops/ng2-events/blob/master/src/once/once.event.ts), which lets you now do the following:

```
<button (once.click)="handleClick($event)">...</button>
```

Comment: I get your point on not removing the event itself. That I don't get is how the listen method in your code example is actually removing the event. It just redirects to `handleClick` which is the called method anyway no?

Comment: The `Renderer.listen()` method returns a function. That function removes the event listener when called [(Angular source)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/dom/events/dom_events.ts#L20).
We assign that returned function to `this.cancelClick`. When we call that, the event listener is removed and `this.handleClick()` is never called again.

Comment: +1. I used this technique for an array of children elements using @ViewChildren() and by storing the functions returned by Renderer.listen() in an array.

Answer (score 3):

For people dealing with `Observable` / `Subject` for handling some events :

```
<button (click)="clickEvents$.next($event)">
```

```
class MyComponent {
  clickEvents$ = new Subject<MouseEvent>();
  firstClick$ = this.clickEvents.take(1); // Observable of first click
}
```