# How to remove an event binding during run time in Angular?

Tags: angular

How can I remove `foo()` handler from `div`in Angular 2+?

```
<div #box (click)="foo($event)"></div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
event.currentTarget.onclick = null
```

Because `event.currentTarget.onclick` is already `null`.

Perhaps, Angular maintains event handlers in a different way.

Comment: share your component code where you code box.nativeElement.onclick = null

Comment: Updated the question a bit. I try simple test: `foo(event: Event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.onclick);
  }`. It returns `null`.

Comment: can you create code snippet?

Comment: If the goal is to remove the event binding after the first click, then it is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41434409/1009922).

Comment: The snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/vm9q86w455

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can help you remove the binding, but something like this may help:

In your component:

```
removeBinding: boolean = false;
```

In your HTML:

```
<div #box (click)="!removeBinding ? (callMyFuncOnce(); removeBinding = true;): ''"></div>
```

Comment: This works great, but I thought there must be a way to achieve the result without creating an additional "flag" variable.

Comment: Right!! Just looking if Renderer can be of any use, I know to access the element in component but donno how to remove the listener.

Comment: The answer could be [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41540342/1009922).