# Remove mouse over and mouse out event after clicking that element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angularjs

I have a input box in which i am toggling the text on mouse over and mouse out event but when I click that box i want to remove mouse hover effect,but after clicking it still changes on mouse hover

```
onMouseOver() {
    this.placeHolder= 'text1';
}

onMouseOut() {
    this.placeHolder = 'text2';
}

onMouseFocus() {
    this.placeHolder ='text3';
}
```

Comment: How are you binding those functions to the `<input>`

Comment: I am working on angular and using property binding

Comment: @RahulOjha Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @AvgustinTomsic angular 12

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434409/angular2-remove-click-event-binding-after-first-click) a possible duplicate.

But short version that I prefer:

**Work with variable**

```
clicked: boolean = false;

onClick() {
  if (!clicked) {
    // Do what you wanna do
    clicked = true; 
  } 
}
```

**Second with html**

```
// Code behind
clicked: boolean = false;

onClick() {
  // Do what you wanna do
  clicked = true; 
}

// HTML
<button (click)="!clicked ? onClick() : null">CLICK ME</button>
```

So, yes, other ways are possible like `removeEventListener` with Angular's renderer2 and so on. But that's not good. Never change the html directly by yourself. Let Angular doing it.